# How to interpret xtologit output?

Tags: panel-data, ordered-logit

so for my research project I am investigating effect a blood pressure diagnosis has on alcohol consumption frequency and physical activity. I have constructed 2 different models for both and I will be using xtologit command as I have panel data.

Please see my output below. My DV is alcohol_freq which is an ordinal variable of 4, which measures days per week the individual drinks. (0-1 1-2- 2 3-5 -3 6-7 -4).

My independent variables are gender (1 is female), net financial wealth, education level, waves( 3 4 5 6) (baseline wave is 2).

```
. xtologit alcohol_freq ragender i.wave i.wealth_group i.raeduc_e   if r2hibps==1, vce(robust)


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                         |               Robust
            alcohol_freq |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                ragender |  -1.779655   .4354061    -4.09   0.000    -2.633036    -.926275
                         |
                    wave |
                      3  |  -.2776735   .1835768    -1.51   0.130    -.6374775    .0821305
                      4  |  -.3572538    .193667    -1.84   0.065    -.7368342    .0223266
                      5  |  -.7242535   .2117997    -3.42   0.001    -1.139373   -.3091337
                      6  |  -.8055891   .2289829    -3.52   0.000    -1.254387   -.3567908
                         |
            wealth_group |
                      2  |   1.923992   .6102358     3.15   0.002     .7279517    3.120032
                      3  |   3.108671   .7094336     4.38   0.000     1.718207    4.499135
                      4  |   4.251541   .7972072     5.33   0.000     2.689043    5.814038
                         |
                raeduc_e |
 3.high-school graduate  |   1.213114   .5658486     2.14   0.032     .1040715    2.322157
         4.some college  |   1.909918   .5798655     3.29   0.001     .7734019    3.046433
    5.college and above  |   2.508408   .7991029     3.14   0.002     .9421947    4.074621
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                   /cut1 |  -1.474018   .8762496    -1.68   0.093    -3.191435    .2434001
                   /cut2 |   1.684593   .8791786     1.92   0.055    -.0385653    3.407752
                   /cut3 |   4.320586   .8989051     4.81   0.000     2.558764    6.082408
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
               /sigma2_u |    14.7487   2.156123                      11.07429    19.64226
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So from my output I guess I can conclude as time went on the no. of days of drinking per week decreased for my sample, and this became stat significant in wave 5.

However I am confused by the positive coefficients for wealth group, education. Does this mean having a higher net wealth would increase frequency of drinking per week over the study? Or I am interpreting this wrong?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Does this mean having a higher net wealth would increase frequency of
>   drinking per week **over the study**?

Probably not over the study. The ORs depicted by the education and income variables are assumed to be independent from wave (aka time) in this model, so for example: it simply means compared with the wealth group 1, the log(odds) of advancing to higher level in the drinking frequency is 4.25 for wealth group 4, adjusted for education, sex, and wave. This 4.25 will be the same in waves 3, 4, 5, and 6.

If you want to look into the association between education and income *overs time* (aka, do some education groups tend to increase their drinking more than other groups over time?), then consider testing the interactions between wave and education and between wave and wealth.

Comment: Ok I will make sure to test the interaction terms, thank you!